# Variadic Enum Parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

Suppose I have an enumeration type like this

```
enum MyEnum {
  case aValue
  case anotherValue
  case thirdValue
  case lastValue
}
```

and a function that takes a variadic parameter of that type

```
func test(values:MyEnum...) {
  // ...
}
```

A call like

```
test(.aValue, .lastValue)
```

perfectly works, the compiler recognizes the calling parameter type with type inference.

Trying to call the function with a single value however

```
test(.aValue) // Error...
```

is refused by the compiler with "'(MyEnum...).Type' does not have a member named 'aValue'". An explicit type is required:

```
test(MyEnum.aValue)
```

The workaround is given by that, but - do I have to consider this as a bug or as a feature of Swift? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 1.2** solution (for the history):

I ended up adding a single-arg overload:

```
func test(values: MyEnum...) {
  doTest(values)
}

func test(value: MyEnum) {
  doTest([value])
}

private func doTest(values: [MyEnum]) {
  // ...
}
```

Looks ugly, but API-wise this is better, I think:

```
test(.aValue)
test(.aValue, .anotherValue)
```

---

**Swift 2.0** single-arg workaround is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem, with the `.` after the `(`, because if you create a external parameter name for the `func` it works just fine.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case aValue
    case anotherValue
    case thirdValue
    case lastValue
}

func test(#values: MyEnum...) {
    print("works") // prints works
}

test(values: .aValue) // no error
```